# IDE Power Switch compatible with any Motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, btx

I have a [Dell Precision T3400](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/precision-t3400/pd), I want to upgrade my MoBo and I found some difficulties, but the one I need help with is:
The power switch cable thingy is connected to a separate card at the front, along with the front audio and 2 USB2.0. This card is then connected to the MoBo with a PATA cable.

My question is if this card at the front works with any motherboard as an alternative to Front audio, USB and Power Switch.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

large branch name machines (like dell) tend to have these unique design quirks. normal consumer motherboards will not have the ribbon connection for this card and so will not be able to use it

Comment: Aww, well that's a shame, anyways most consumer MoBos are ATX or miniATX so, I guess I'll switch the case.  
I really wanted to use the same case because it's very resistant and it has a good design for cooling :p

Comment: if you go for something small - like mITX you could always mod it to fit with a dremel and drill or something.